# System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures returning null in dev environment (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7

First of all, this could very well be a rookie mistake on my part, I'm fairly new to .net and c#.

I'm using the CMS system Umbraco on our latest project, and a recent update has meant the system has started using the System.Globalization.CultureInfo class to deal with localization. This has resulted in multiple "Culture Not Found" errors in the CMS back office that renders it unusable. Here's a stack trace from one of them:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
.-no is an invalid culture identifier.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
.-no is an invalid culture identifier.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
.-no is an invalid culture identifier.]
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String name) +12488971
   Umbraco.Core.Services.LocalizedTextServiceFileSources.<.ctor>b__0() +573
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +180
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +26
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +12446617
   Umbraco.Core.Services.LocalizedTextServiceFileSources.TryConvert2LetterCultureTo4Letter(String twoLetterCulture) +61
   Umbraco.Core.Services.LocalizedTextService.ConvertToSupportedCultureWithRegionCode(CultureInfo currentCulture) +110
   Umbraco.Core.Services.LocalizedTextService.GetAllStoredValues(CultureInfo culture) +72
   Umbraco.Web.Editors.BackOfficeController.LocalizedText(String culture) +123
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +77
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9765121
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I'm still not completely sure where the .-no is coming from, but after some amount of research into this I tried running the following code with a breakpoint inserted:

```
var locale = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
```

This returned null, and doesn't seem to be throwing an exception anywhere. I'm guessing this might be the cause of the errors, judging by the stack trace. Could this be an issue with my local setup? I'm running Windows 10, mainly in a virtualization environment, but it can also run natively via OSX Bootcamp, where the problem still seems to be present. I've also tried using Powershell to output the list of installed cultures, and that works fine.

If it helps, I'm using IISExpress for the web server and the database is running under SQL Server 2016 Express.

Thanks in advance! Let me know if I can supply any extra info to help out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the fact that Umbraco is open source.

Judging from the stack trace and exception details you have provided, problem is caused by this line:

https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/dev-v7/src/Umbraco.Core/Services/LocalizedTextServiceFileSources.cs#L102

Apparently invalid value `.-no` is passed into `GetCultureInfo` method. If you look a bit up in the source code, it seems that this value comes from XML file name or XML file content.

I cannot provide complete solution for your problem, but here are some things to try to pinpoint root cause of it:

**1) Clean deployment folder**

Do full clean & rebuild cycle

**2) Check localization XML files to check if they contain valid cultures**

If you have edited files manually, make sure there is no typo there.

**3) Compare folders of "fresh" install and your non-working solution folder**

Check if update hasn't left behind some XML files from previous versions;

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. I've tried running some of the Umbraco methods further back down the trace and it seems to default to the "en" culture when querying the XML files in question. What's slightly odd is that System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en") or "en-US" / "en-GB" on my dev environment returns null. Any reason why this would be?